# What is Visual Studio's Font Cache folder?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, fonts

I started playing around with an app called [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) today and I have noticed that this folder:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\Font Cache\
```

...takes up to 10GB on my computer, containing font files.
Does anyone have any idea what this folder is for and if it is safe to delete it?

10GB is too much and the folder name with "cache" in it makes me want to delete it...

Comment: I have multiple versions of VS installed (2008 through 2015) and I do not see this "Font Cache" folder anywhere on my system. What kind of files are present?

Comment: There are MANY folders with random names like `0atsat4t.qha` each one containing only one font file called "ARIALUNI.TTF". I have the impression that it might be related to WPF, but I am not sure... :(

Comment: The Font-Cache is indeed for WPF. It stores information about the font, I suspect for improved rendering speed by pre-calculating kerning and scaling information. It'll probably be regenerated when you delete it. Any chance you have Photoshop installed or any other designer tool that ships with loads of fonts?

Comment: @jessehouwing My computer had Photoshop Essentials pre-installed, but in the `Font Cache` folder I only see the `ARIALUNI.TTF` font present, which is a Windows font.

Comment: It looks like your Font-Cache service went haywire. In the windows services make sure you stop all versions of the Font cache (there will be multiple under different names), delete the contents of the font-cache folder and then reboot. It should rebuild and hopefully won't do 1000 copies for each font this time round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK.
I have found what causes this.

I had a WPF demo project in VS2012 that had that particular font included in it and it had been configured to copy it in the output directory.
Turns out that VS will copy the font files in the cache folder every time:

- You open a new WPF project that has a font file included in it (at least when configured to copy it in the output directory).
- You include a new font file in the WPF project.

The thing is that it doesn't delete them in the end (when you close VS).

I don't know if the font cache service (that I have some difficulty locating right now) should do that, but apparently no-one does on my machine for some reason and for quite some time... These files must have been accumulating for over a year now...

I have also deleted the folder contents without seeing any problems.

10GB less! :)

Comment: Same problem, same solution :).

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aa7b8449-fd93-4f91-a602-26ce1b73dc85/clear-font-cache-wpf-windows-vista?forum=wpf) describes how to disable the font cache:

> You can disable the WPF font cache by following these steps:
>
> 1. Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services
> 2. Scroll down to `Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 3.0.0.0`, right-click and select **Properties**
> 3. In the window then select **Disabled** in the startup type combo